# Error when checking target: expected activation_final to have shape (60,) but got array with shape (4,)

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, keras

```
# train the model
start = dt.now()
show = my_model.fit_generator(
# training data
train_generator,

# epochs
steps_per_epoch = train_generator.n // 32, #floor per batch size
epochs = 15, 

# validation data
validation_data = test_images_iter,
validation_steps = test_images_iter.n // 32,

#  print progress
verbose = 1,
callbacks = [
#early stopping in case the loss stops decreasing
k.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3),
# only save the model if the monitored quantity (val_loss or val_acc) has improved
k.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("fruits_checkpoints.h5", monitor='val_loss', save_best_only = True),
# only needed for visualising with TensorBoard
k.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir = "logs/{:%d_%b_%Y_%H:%M:%S}".format(dt.now()) )
```

]
)
I am gettin this error idk how to fix it i a newbe to ML
Error when checking target: expected activation_final to have shape (60,) but got array with shape (4,)

Answer (score 1):

replace test_images_iter with test generator
    validation data
    validation_data = test_generator,
    validation_steps = test_generator.n // 32,